# snmpwalk: settings are not populated in the SNMP requests

Tags: snmpwalk

I use snmpwalk 5.9.3 on Kali, and try to send SNMPv3 requests, but the settings I put with my command lines are not used to populate the sent request.

For instance, when I try:
`snmpwalk -v 3 -l authPriv -u my_user -a SHA-256 -A auth_password -x AES-256 -X priv_password 192.168.0.1`

and look at the sent requests in Wireshark, I get:
[snmp wireshark trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZEJ5.png)

Why are my settings not used in the sent request?

I tried sending SNMP requests with v 1 et 2c and set a community, which worked as expected, so my issue is only when I use v 3.